# appcmd add vdir /IN < fileWithVdirConfig.xml ERROR

Tags: appcmd, iisvdir

I am trying to automate the deployment of sites with appcmd.

I have the website and app pools working correctly.  I get the settings in a xml config file with:

```
appcmd list site "bleh" /config /xml
```

I save these off to xml files and will go into Source control.  I create the sites and app pools with a command such as:

```
appcmd add site /IN < fileWithSiteSettings.xml
```

This works great until I try and do it with a virtual directory.  I get the following error:

```
ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer for VDIR object with verb ADD. )
```

I have tried Googling this but can't find much.  My goal is to be able to automatically deploy a site or service or collection of them to N number of machines via the CI server build process.  Not sure why the vdir is acting differently than the others.

Here is the settings from the xml file for the vdir:

```
<appcmd>
    <VDIR physicalPath="C:\site\WebSite" path="/" APP.NAME="Default Web Site/myvdir" VDIR.NAME="Default Web Site/myvdir/">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\site\WebSite" />
    </VDIR>
</appcmd>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is occurring because you are trying to add a site with a file that only contains Virtual Directory Information.  Try the command

```
appcmd add vdir /IN < fileWithSiteSettings.xml
```

and I think you will have better luck.

Presumably you are trying to add a virtual directory to an existing site, and thus the export of the VDIR only. Otherwise you should be exporting the entire site, and then loading it using your original command.

Comment: oh, that makes sense.  So to just have virtual driectories settings in a config file I would need to either export a whole site and remove the settings that were not required, or export the vdir and add the site settings.... if the site already exists, (same name at least), I assume it will just add the vdir to that site happily?

Comment: absolutely, I just exported a virtual directory locally, changed the config file so that it would load it to another, and then ran the query.  It worked fine.

Comment: Hi pms, I have just got back to this project. I am rather confused as to exactly how you did it.  I.e. how you backed up the settings for one VDIR in a website that has multiple then restored that to a different website (or changed its name and restored to the same website).  I am trying to wrap the VDIR xml element in the site xml but to no avail.  Sounds logical what your saying but just can't seem to get it.

Comment: think I answered my own question with the aid of, http://forums.iis.net/t/1176391.aspx basically a vdir only points at files, what I want is an app to be able to add it into a website.

Answer (score 2):

I got `ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer for VDIR object with verb ADD. )` today, and solved it by adding a trailing `/` to the site name.